# How to send a query result through mail with xls extension

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to send an email notification using SQL Server msdb and by formatting my body to HTML.

I want to know if it's possible to send the attachment file as an Excel or `.csv` file.

Here's my code :

```
  Declare @HTMLbody nvarchar(max),
    @NumChassis varchar(100),
    @Marque varchar(100),
    @Modele varchar(100),
    @Finition varchar(100),
    @SQL nvarchar(max)
    set @SQL =''
    Set @HTMLbody = '<!DOCTYPE html> <head><title>Aging stock notification</title></head><body>'
    set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + '<center><h1> Notification des véhicules en stock</h1></center> '
    set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + '<center><p> Vous pouvez visualisez la  liste des chassis en stock depuis plus de 120 jours pièces jointes  </p> </center>'
    set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + ' <center> '



set @HTMLbody = @HTMLbody + @SQL + '</table> </center> <center><a href="http://Dashboard"><b>Voir plus de détails sur le tableau de bord</b> </a></center> '

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name = 'Admin_smtp',  
@body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = 'MAIL',  
@body =  @HTMLbody,  
@query = 'select top(10) a.NUM_CHASSIS,a.MARQUE,a.MODELE,a.FINITION ,DATEDIFF(DAY, a.DATE_FIN_OF, GETDATE()) as Age from [DashboardPowerBi].[dbo].[BI_SVC_PROD_FIN_OF] as a
 join [DashboardPowerBi].[dbo].[BI_SVC_INCADEA_STOCK_VN] as b 
  on a.NUM_CHASSIS = b.VIN
  where b.CMD_Vente_Incadea = 0 and b.Fact_Av_Incadea =1 and DATEDIFF(DAY, a.DATE_FIN_OF, GETDATE()) > 120',
@subject = 'This is a test',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1 ;
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't know what Excel is. So to get it into XLS format you'll probably have to use something external to SQL Server - like, run the query from Powershell, and have Powershell generate the file from the output, and then have Powershell e-mail it.

Comment: This need would be right up SSRS's alley.  Create an SSRS report that contains your content, and then set up an email subscription to deliver it on whatever schedule you need.  Can send in various formats, including CSV and Excel.